# how to create multiple subfolders in pyhton using subprocess?

Tags: 20.04, bash, python3, mkdir

On my ubuntu 20.04 when I use

```
mkdir -p /home/parent/{child1,child2}
```

in my terminal I get a folder parent with 2 subfolders child1 and child2.

- parent
- parent/child1
- parent/child2

However, when I try to run this in a python script using

```
bashCommand = "mkdir -p /home/parent/{child1,child2}"
#print(bashCommand)
subprocess.run(bashCommand.split(), capture_output=True)
```

I end up having a parent folder and one child folder named {child1,child2}.

- parent
- parent/{child1,child2}

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `subprocess`, but `os.mkdir()` or `os.makedirs()`.

Comment: I recommend that too, but for the general case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659579/curly-braces-in-python-popen